# Unauthorized error while executing a REST Api using Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to automate a REST Api. and I am getting an Unauthorized error after execution. Kindly suggest the changes needed.

Following are the steps:

1. I am capturing cookies from the browser.
2. Updating the value of timeoutTracker cookie.
3. Adding cookies to the Http client.
4. Then executing the API.
5. Checking the status code.

Actual: Unauthorized Error code.
Expected: Success with the response of the API in the console.

```
using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver())
 {
     try
     {
         // Navigate to the website to set the cookies
         driver.Url = "http://10.3.4.7/";
         driver.FindElement(By.Id("cphMain_txtUsername")).SendKeys("ajain");
         driver.FindElement(By.Id("cphMain_txtPassword")).SendKeys("TriPass99@");
         driver.FindElement(By.Id("cphMain_btnLogIn")).Click();
         Thread.Sleep(3000);
         driver.FindElement(By.Id("MainContent_ctl01_gvCompanies_lnkSites_5")).Click();
         Thread.Sleep(5000);
         driver.Url = "http://10.3.4.7/admin/devices?companyId=4&siteId=1000";
         // Get cookies from the browser
         var cookies = driver.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies;


         // updating timeoutTracker cookie
         var cookieToUpdate = cookies.FirstOrDefault(cookie => cookie.Name == "timeoutTracker");

         if (cookieToUpdate != null)
         {
             // Update the value of the cookie
             driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteCookieNamed("timeoutTracker");

             // Create a new cookie with the updated value
             var updatedCookie = new OpenQA.Selenium.Cookie("timeoutTracker", "2024-04-13T11:20:52.4198343-07:00",cookieToUpdate.Domain, cookieToUpdate.Path, cookieToUpdate.Expiry);

             // Add the updated cookie
             driver.Manage().Cookies.AddCookie(updatedCookie);
         }
         cookies = driver.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies;
         
        

         // Add cookies to HttpClient
        
         HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
          handler.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
          Console.WriteLine("Cookie Starting");
         foreach (var cookie in cookies)
         {
             handler.CookieContainer.Add(new Uri("http://10.3.4.7/"), new System.Net.Cookie(cookie.Name, cookie.Value));
             Console.WriteLine(cookie.Name + ": " + cookie.Value);
         }


          Console.WriteLine("Cookie printing ends");

         //executing api
          HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
          // Example REST API request
          HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("http://10.3.4.7/api/company/4/site/1000/device/getalldevicesalarmdefinitions?status=All&pageNumber=1&pageSize=10").Result;

          // Example: Display response content
          if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
          {
              string responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
              Console.WriteLine("API Response:");
              Console.WriteLine(responseContent);
          }
          else
          {
              Console.WriteLine("API request failed. Status code: " + response.StatusCode);
          }   
     }
     finally
     {
         // Close the browser
         driver.Quit();
     }
 }
```

Comment: How does your API authenticate and authorize API calls? Are you able to make API calls using an API client such as curl, Insomnia, or Postman? Typically REST APIs don't use cookies for authentication, they use Bearer tokens (either static keys or OAuth2/OpenID Connect). The fact you're using browser automation to simulate a user logging in and using the cookies from that session seems odd.

Comment: If i talk about testing it manually,
1. We can browse "10.3.4.7" and then log in to the portal.
2. if we browse the GET API in parallel tab, the request executes.

Thru Postman
1.  we need to capture the cookies from the browser first.
2. Then we need to execute the GET request.

Comment: Why would you use cookies for authentication with REST APIs?

Comment: That is how 'developers' have crafted the API.

Comment: If you search in chatGPT, "Need to capture cookies from the browser for executing the REST API using Selenium C#" you may expect similar code in the output.

Comment: seems like you'd need: HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);  As is, I don't see you using the handler at all.